# Data from database to Label

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlcommand

I would like to get data from my database to my label.

This is my code:

```
con = new SqlConnection(conS);

try
{
    con.Open();
    string q = "SELECT SearchTerm FROM Sentiment WHERE Sentiment = 'positive'";

    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(q, con);

    using (SqlDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader())
    {
        bool success = dr.Read();

        if (success)
        {
            // Label1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
            label3.Text = dr.GetString(1);
        }
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    label3.Text = "Error";
}
```

However when I run the application, my label is showing 'Error'. What is wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You are getting an `exception`, debug your code.

Comment: Did you tried to debug and see what is the exception ? Can you elaborate on the connection string?

Comment: First, dont show `label3.Text = "Error";` in your exception. it's not informative. You can use `label3.Text = ex.Message;` to get a detail ed error. Second one, make sure the query is returning only 1 record. try to change the code to `SELECT TOP 1 SearchTerm FROM Sentiment WHERE Sentiment = 'positive'`

Comment: when debugged, it says index was outside the bounds of the array. What does this means?

Comment: try 'label3.Text = dr.GetString(0);'

Answer (score 1):

Try to Get `Top 1` record using select query.

```
 string q = "SELECT TOP 1 SearchTerm FROM Sentiment WHERE Sentiment = 'positive'";
```

and

```
label3.Text = dr.GetString(0);
```

Hope it will help.